# Address Book Authorization in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, abaddressbook

I have a problem to get the permission to access the AddressBook since I updated on iOS 8.

In iOS 7 the system asks the user whether my App is allowed to access his AddressBook but since iOS8 there haven't been any requests. Every time I check for the ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus before I start my "MyGetAddressesOfContacts" function, the Status is equal to kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined.
Like you can see here:

```
if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusDenied)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No permission" message:@"This App has no permition to access your contacts. Please check it in your privacy settings of your device." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];

    return nil;
}

// This AlertView pops up every time!
if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Why this App needs your contacts" message:@"In the following your device will ask you whether this App is allowed to access your contacts. [...]" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"I understand" otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [alert show];
}
```

After this check I am going to start the MyGetAddressesOfContacts function which looks like this:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
NSArray *contactArr = (NSArray *)CFBridgingRelease(ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook));
NSMutableDictionary *dPersons = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < [contactArr count]; i++)
{
    ABRecordRef person = (ABRecordRef)CFBridgingRetain([contactArr objectAtIndex:i]);
    NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    NSString *lastName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
    NSString *sPersonName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];

    ABMultiValueRef address = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty);
    NSString *sAddress;

    for(CFIndex j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(address); j++)
    {
        CFDictionaryRef addressDict = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(address, j);

        CFStringRef streetValue = CFDictionaryGetValue(addressDict, kABPersonAddressStreetKey);
        CFStringRef cityValue = CFDictionaryGetValue(addressDict, kABPersonAddressCityKey);
        CFStringRef countryValue = CFDictionaryGetValue(addressDict, kABPersonAddressCountryKey);

        sAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@, %@", streetValue, cityValue, countryValue];
        [dPersons setObject:sAddress forKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d %ld", @"AddressFromNameID", i, j]];
    }

    [dPersons setObject:sPersonName forKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d", @"NameWithID", i]];
}

return dPersons;
```

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you created AB ...

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
```

call the following ...

```
ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, nil);
```

This will display prompt for user to allow your application access "contacts"; As the second parameter you may get result callback and behave accordingly. Please refer to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion)